# cvSetImageData and cvCreateImage c++ equivalent interface

Tags: c++, c, opencv, legacy-code, data-conversion

Is there any c++ opencv interface that can do the same operation of these two functions?

Hi, I'm actually using these two functions in this way

```
IplImage *image;
ARUint8 *dataPtr; // unsigned chars, in format ARGB
cv::Size size;

//do stuff

image = cvCreateImage(*size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, channels );

cvSetImageData( image, dataPtr, size->width * channels );
```

The fitst one creates is used to initialize an empty IplImage *image, the second one to copy the raw data from an external source (dataPtr) to the image itself.

I know that the first one should be trivial, replacing the IplImage con un cv::Mat, the problem is that I don't know how to pass the parameter "IPL_DEPTH_8U" to the constructor.

To copy the data with the c++ interface, i have no clue...

PS: ARUint8 *dataPtr is my source of data, I cannot have another source, but then I need to convert it to opencv data representation

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Like you suspected, in the C++ interface you do this via the constructor for `cv::Mat`. You will have to use the appropriate type corresponding to `IPL_DEPTH_8U` (probably `CV_8U` or `CV_8UC3` depending on how many channels you have).

One of the constructor overloads can take a raw pointer to existing data, so you could do it like this:

```
cv::Mat image(size, CV_8U, (void*)dataPtr);
```

Note also that the cv::Mat constructor can take a `step` argument, which is needed if your data has padding at the end of the rows, or any other more complicated format.

You can also always browse the OpenCV [documentation for Mat::Mat online](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) for more details.